# Does replacing ad units in AdSense affect earnings due to history with the specific placements?

Tags: web-development, google-adsense, blogger

I created a website using blogger.com and I have AdSense ads in that website. Sometimes I remove Adsense Ads from the blogger template and create new Adsense ads to replace them.

Then I noticed that when I remove existing ads and create new ads, the revenue goes down. I think this is not because of amount of clicks I get from ads but from the impressions.

So does AdSense analyse historical data of individual ads when they calculate earnings I get from the impressions? If so, how much time they analyse back? Is it like seven days, one month, or something else?